# Trace Web Service calls in the Console Hosting Application

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have Web Service and very simple Console Hosting Application:

```
ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
host.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Running");
Console.ReadKey();
host.Close();
```

And I have another applications which call methods of my Web Service:

```
ServiceReference.MyServiceClient proxy = new ServiceReference.MyServiceClient();
proxy.GetData("one");
```

Is it possible to log on the console window of hosting application informations about the service calls ?

Something like:

```
The Service method GetData was called with the parameter "one".
```

Comment: what do you mean with "the service calls" ? you can do your usual `WriteLine`'s and different loggers, unless I'm not following the question ...

Comment: I've answered your updated question, have you seen it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Assuming you have a contract :

```
[OperationContract]
void SomeMethod();
```

and a Service implementation:

```
public void SomeMethod() 
{ 
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Somebody called SomeMethod" );
    // Do whatever else you need
}
```

When you call the method, it will print to the console.

Comment: Thanks.  I need a little time to check your answer.

Comment: Glad it helped. I will suggest having a logger do the work for you, or even connect it to Growl to get a popup if you'll run it as a windows service and not in a console. I'll shamelessly suggest my articles on [NLog](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/749612/How-to-NLog-with-VisualStudio) and [How to Growl with NLog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/786304/Logging-How-to-Growl-with-NLog-or) if you're interested :)

Comment: What do yo say about log4net ? Can I use it to log WCF service calls ?

Comment: Of course you can. When I had looked at both, NLog seemed to be better. Not sure if log4net is still developed actively though.